# Is the equality $1^2+\cdots + 24^2 = 70^2$ just a coincidence?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

I have read a [question](https://twitter.com/ElfenLied_MS2/status/745999283653074945) (written in Korean. *Added on September 9, 2020: the link is broken, unfortunately.*) that the equality
$$1^2+2^2+\cdots + 24^2 = 70^2$$
is just a coincidence or not. It is related to the integral points of the following elliptic curve (?):
$$y^2 = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x.$$

(To note, its determinant is $1/1296$.)

I have heard that finding the integral points of an elliptic curve is very hard in general, so my first goal is to find rational solutions to it. However, I have not learned of the number theory so I have no idea how to find rational points of that.

Is there any idea to solve this? Furthermore, is there an idea to find integral points of it? I would be appreciated for your help!

Comment: You might find the formula $1^2+2^2+\dots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ helpful.

Comment: @carmichael561 Thanks but I know it. The elliptic curve I have written is based on that formula.

Comment: $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(24,70)$ seem to be the only solutions. [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+m%5E2%3D(n*(n%2B1)*(2*n%2B1))%2F6+in+integers) thinks so.

Comment: You may find [this pdf](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/numbers/24.pdf) interesting.

Comment: @pjs36 Thanks! It seems quite interesting.

Comment: http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/71079/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=71097#71097

Comment: @individ I have not leaned of Russian so I can't read this. Would you summarize it brifely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one solution(except $1=1$). There is a proof in Mordell's book on Diophantine Equations. The problem is attributed to Lucas:

> with N > 1 is when N = 24 and M = 70. This is known as the cannonball
>   problem, since it can be visualized as the problem of taking a square
>   arrangement of cannonballs on the ground and building a square pyramid
>   out of them. It was not until 1918 that a proof (using elliptic
>   functions) was found for this remarkable fact, which has relevance to
>   the bosonic string theory in 26 dimensions.[1](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Lucas-Square-Pyramid-Problem-Revisited-Bennett/c549b56b3667e37035e54cd0383eeec8e5813331/pdf) More recently,
>   elementary proofs have been published.[2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985859)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Lucas

[Here is a discussion and proof by Bennett](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Lucas-Square-Pyramid-Problem-Revisited-Bennett/c549b56b3667e37035e54cd0383eeec8e5813331/pdf)

[Elementary proof by Anglin](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323911?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

The fact is critically important in the history of the Leech Lattice, the history of finite simple groups, Monstrous Moonshine and other cute things. See page 130 in Ebeling *Lattices and Codes* (second edition), I will try to find it in [SPLAG as well. Yes page 524 in the first edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985859), chapter *Lorentzian Forms for the Leech Lattice*.

Answer (score 6):

Not a coincidence, definitely. $70$ is a [Pell number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellNumber.html), so $2\cdot 70^2+1=99^2$, and some solutions of

$$ 1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = q^2 $$
can be derived by imposing that both $2n+1$ and $\frac{n(n+1)}{6}$ are squares: that leads to a Pell equation.